# Prevent scrolling on "lower" div

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have on my website a sidebar that can come out from the side on mobile. It is a fixed element, which does not play nice on mobile browsers. I want to prevent being able to scroll the body of the document in order to fix this when scrolling on the sidebar div (but I still want them to be able to scroll the sidebar if there is an overflow).

Here is a video of what I want to prevent:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqWll2G2Km8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: If you add to your fixed sidebar `z-index: 100500;` ... that doesn't help?

Comment: Sadly, no; I attempted that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding exactly what you are looking for, but I'm working on a section of a site right now that requires this type of sidebar that comes out from the side of the page. At first it was doing exactly the same thing for me as well, where the body would scroll while I was scrolling the sidebar content. After some testing it seems whether position: fixed or position: absolute, the only time the page allows me to scroll the side bar and not the content is when I set the

```
.main-sidebar-container { position: fixed; bottom: 0; }
```

There are other styles in there as well, but that bottom: 0 seems to be the key to allowing the side bar to scroll while not scrolling the body. I know you don't need to scroll your side bar but maybe setting your main-sidebar-container to bottom: 0 will help in this situation as well. I'll let you know if I come across any other findings as I continue with my own project. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found was that if the sidebar is currently active, use JS to set the html height to 100% and overflow to hidden. Not sure how good this is in practice, though.